# JavascriptSerializer and RegisterConverter()

Tags: json, serialization, c#-4.0

(oh, by the way, sorry for my english)
I want to know how can be a simple implementation of RegisterConverter() To convert a DateTime with a JavascriptSerializer, cause I'm having some troubles with it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one: http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2011/12/custom-datetime-json-serialization/